# Storyboards: what is the "Index Row Limit" field?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit, uistoryboard

In Storyboards, TableViews have an attribute field named "Index Row Limit".  The default is 2.  I cannot find any information on what this is.  A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=xcode%20%22index%20row%20limit%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) returns a single page of results and half of the results are non-English.  Does anyone know what this field is for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's related to the `sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount` property on `UITableView`. Basically, if you have less than that many rows in the table, any section index will be hidden. (The section index is the bar on the right hand side of the table that usually has the letters A-Z, which lets you quickly jump through the list.)

**Update**:
I've verified that setting the "Index Row Limit" in the .xib or .storyboard does indeed change a value in the underlying XML titled `sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount`, so it's clear that's what this property is supposed to be related to. However, it also appears that there's a bug in UITableView (at least as of iOS 5.1), such that the setting in Interface Builder isn't actually being properly set on the object when it is unarchived at runtime. Time to file a radar!

Comment: I did some experiments and this answer does not seems to be correct.  I created a table with 18 sections and 54 total rows and 18 index rows.  The index was always displayed, even if I set Index Row Limit to 80.  I also checked the value of sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount, and it always defaulted to 0 regardless of what Index Row Limit was set to.  changing sectionIndexMinDispRowCount DID affect the display of the index as your answer indicates.

Comment: Hm. So, changing the "Index Row Limit" in a storyboard file causes only a single change in the actual XML. That change is for an attribute on the `<tableview>` element, titled `sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount`. So it seems fairly clear that whether or not it works correctly, this is the *intended* functionality.

Comment: My test results did not change the loaded value of that property at all.  Did yours?  Is this a bug in Xcode?  What version are you using?  I'm using 4.2.1.

Comment: I just tried it with Xcode 4.4.1, and it's not working there either. It looks like a bug in UIKit.

Comment: I reported this to Apple.  I'm giving you credit since it seems that the storyboard field name corresponds to a known property.

Answer (score 0):

This value is **used to decide when to show the special index list on the right side of table view**.*If the row count(total number of rows) of table view is greater than or equal to this number the index list on right side of table view is shown else not shown*.

Here's the UIKit Documentation:

`open var sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount: Int // show special section index list on right when row count reaches this value. default is 0`